# Remove a space character in string

Tags: java

I am reading each line in the text file, do some with the file and write back to same file using Java.  And, position(index) of each value in the line is important. So I need to preserve the location of the each value.

How do I remove a "space" character at specific location(index)?

Say, below is the line that I read,

```
.... ABC   123....  --There are 3 spaces between ABC and 123
```

Basically, I want to make the above line written as 2 spaces between ABC and 123.

At first, I was just using replaceAll of String but that just shift the the values to right by one and still 3 spaces.  So, I figure I need more than just replaceAll.

Now, I am getting a position of where ABC is found and just trying to remove that 1 space.

Comment: `str.replace("ABC   123", "ABC  123");` or if you know the position of the space `new StringBuilder(str).deleteCharAt(pos).toString()`

Comment: Are you using `\s` to represent space in your search pattern ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove a single character, just use `StringBuilder.deleteCharAt`.

```
final int pos = ...;
str = new StringBuilder(str).deleteCharAt(pos).toString();
```

I explicitly advise you *not* to do the `substring` approach.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do a search for the whole string? The first parameter has three spaces and the second has two spaces

```
replaceAll("ABC   123", "ABC  123");
```

or if ABC is your key input

```
replaceAll("ABC   ", "ABC  ");
```

and the first parameter has 3 spaces and the second two after the ABC

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the position n (zero based) of string s that you want to remove:

```
s = s.substring(0, n) + s.substring(n + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just convert your string to a char array and loop it, but it's not a nice way to do it.

Or you could do:

```
myString = myString.substring(0,(position of first space))+
                myString.substring((position of first space)+1, myString.length);
```

or something like that